# Geometry High School Olympiad

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I really need help with this problem, I don't seem to understand it all... 
I've drawn out the diagram but I don't know where to begin. I would like a hint, to help me understand how to solve this problem or where to begin.

> Let $ABCD$ be a square of side length $1234$. $E$ is a point on $CD$ such that $CEFG$ is a square of side length $567$ with $F$ and $G$ outside $ABCD$. The circumcircle of triangle $ACF$ meets $BC$ again at $H$. Find $CH$.

After this diagram is drawn and all the points are labeled,I need to find the length of $CH$. But for me it is unclear where to begin with this problem, such that using the information given, I can find out the length of CH.

Comment: Hint: $AC\perp CF$.

Comment: $AF$ is a diameter, so the midpoint of that line is a horizontal axis of symmetry for the circle. Thus $|BH|=567$...